# Cassandra Consistency Level In Some Special Scenario

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cql, eventual-consistency

Consider a cluster of 4 nodes.

The replication factor has been set to 3.

We gave a write query with consistency level set to ALL but only one of the replicas successfully wrote the data and the other two never responded. (crashed during write)

In this situation, the coordinator responds with `TimeOutException` so we think that our request failed to persist.

Then we gave a read query for the same row_key with consistency level set to 1, coordinator sends this request to the same node which was successfully written the previous request.

My question is what happens next? whether this read query returns with value? and if so does this behavior really make any sense because we threw UnavailableException in the first place?

Comment: I was incorrect with my answer... I just checked the code - there is a check (in the `StorageProxy.java`) before writing the data to check if we're able to reach given CL at all. So in this case we shouldn't send write request to any node.

Comment: You are right Alex but I am more interested in the situation in which the coordinator thinks that all nodes are fine but some of them suddenly crash during a write operation.

Comment: Ok, then it's a different situation, let me undelete my answer & modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was modified after clarification

Cassandra can answer early with `UnavailableException` if it has information (based on Gossip) that given CL won't be achieved as it doesn't have enough replicas.

Coordinator node will attempt to write to all required replicas, and if some of them crashed during the operation, then coordinator may write a hint for them, that will be replayed after nodes are back (during 3 hours by default). Coordinator node should return `WriteTimeoutException` or `WriteFailureException`.

Even if the nodes aren't back, and you're reading with `ONE` or `LOCAL_ONE`, then you can get data back. This is what called Eventual Consistency - data will be eventually propagated to all replicas - either via hints or via repairs.

You can find more information on how Cassandra writes & reads data with consistency levels in the [DataStax Architecture Guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/dse-arch/datastax_enterprise/dbInternals/dbIntDataConsistencyTOC.html).

Comment: DataStax document says UnavailableException throws when the coordinator knows that the consistency level can not be met without sending any write message.

Comment: But if the coordinator think that consistency level could be met then it sends write messages to designated nodes and waits, now if there was a problem with nodes which makes them unable to write then coordinator returns timed out exception which indicates the request was unsuccessful, but there is a possibility that some nodes actually wrote the data and if you execute some read command you may see your data. I think this does not make any sense because we do not expect to see the result.